# Steps to take in order to register an external login using Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm having a lot of trouble finding an example of how to wire up a client to use external auth in a web api service. Any questions I find similar to this have responses pointing to the same couple of blog entries:

[This one with an Angular front end](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/)

[And this one on the Microsoft website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services#FQDN)

I really just want to know what AJAX calls I need to make to the service in order to register and login to it using external authentication. If anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it. This has turned into a frustrating ordeal that should have been pretty straight forward.

Comment: be a bit more specific about what have you done and configured until now.